# Add environment property to @SpringBootTest before application.properties evaluation?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test

Is it possible to add a "dynamic" property from a class to `application.properties` before they are evaluated?

I want to achieve the following: find a free port on the system, inject it as property `mockPort` into the spring lifecycle, and reuse this port to override a property from `application.properties` using `@TestPropertySource`, as follows:

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(properties = "web.client.url=localhost:${mockPort}/path")
public class MyWebTest {
               //TODO how to write the port into ${mockPort} property?
               private static final PORT = SocketUtils.findAvailableTcpPort();
 
               @BeforeEach
               public void init() {
                   MockWebServer mock = new MockWebServer();
                   mock.start(PORT);
               }
 
               @Test
               public void test() {
                   service.runWebRequest();
               }
}
```

The service under test can be any client that makes use of `@Value("${web.client.url})`. And as the free port is found dynamically during runtime, I have to somehow inject it into that property.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Spring Framework's `@DynamicPropertySource` for this purpose. It's described in [this blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2020/03/27/dynamicpropertysource-in-spring-framework-5-2-5-and-spring-boot-2-2-6).

In the case of `MyWebTest`, the dynamic property source would look something like this:

```java
@DynamicPropertySource
static void mockPortProperty(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
    registry.add("mockPort", () -> PORT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you prefer to start a single MockWebServer for all test classes, instead of starting a new server for each test method. When this class is initialized, the static block starts a server and sets a system property to the server URL. [System properties override](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config) properties from the `application.properties` file.

```java
@TestConfiguration
public class MockWebServerConfiguration {

  private static final MockWebServer mockWebServer = new MockWebServer();

  static {
    int port = SocketUtils.findAvailableTcpPort();
    mockWebServer.start(port);

    System.setProperty("web.client.url", "localhost:" + port + "/path");
  }
}
```

To include this configuration class in your integration test, annotate your test class with:

```java
@Import(MockWebServerConfiguration.class)
```